# Functional derivative or chain rule?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Just a quick question... I have two functions – $V(a,b,c)$ and $F(a,b,c)$ – and I wish to calculate the derivative of one with respect to another ($\frac{\partial V}{\partial F}$). Am I right in thinking that this is a functional derivative, and must be calculated using something like:

$\frac{\delta V}{\delta F} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial F} - \nabla \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nabla F}$

Rather than just an application of the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial F} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial F} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial F} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial F}$

I'm not that familiar with functional derivatives – would someone be able to point me to a straightforward practical example of a functional derivative calculation, if that is indeed required?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: I always have troubles with such questions. Suppose that $V(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ and $F(a,b,c)=a^2-b^2=3c^2$. What $\partial V / \partial F$ should be?

Comment: The concept of "partial derivative with respect to a function" doesn't make sense. You take partial derivatives with respect to a *variable* (where it is understood that this variable is one of the variables in a given coordinate system, and that the other variables are to be held constant).